# Have to run the "sodu dhclient eth1" after reboot

Tags: wireless

Is there a solution for not having to run the above command manually every time after reboot, in order for the Wi-fi to connect to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

Try WiCd instead: See http://wicd.sourceforge.net - Recommending because I've had much better experience with it than the standard network manager.